# Check for a key in a map and the value is not null using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I would like to know if using streams, if the following code can be refactored.

```
BiFunction<ClassA, ClassB, Boolean> function = (a, b) -> {
    Map<String, String> theMap   = a.getMap();
    String              theKey   = b.getKey();
    String              theValue = theMap.get(theKey);
    return !StringUtils.isBlank(theValue);
};
```

thus:

1. First we get  map from object a
2. Then we get a key from object b
3. We check if there is a value for the key in the map
4. The value is not blank

something like (not real code):

```
BiFunction<ClassA, ClassB, Boolean> function = (a, b) -> {
 return a.getMap().entrySet().stream()
    .map(Entry::getKey).filter(b.getKey()::equals)
    .map(Entry::getValue).filter(!StringUtils::isBlank);
};
```

Comment: Do you really think streams are cleaner for such a representation? Besides you end up iterating all entries despite the `.get` on `Map`. Alternatively, your first code block could be similar to `BiFunction<ClassA, ClassB, Boolean> function = (a, b) ->
                !a.getMap().getOrDefault(b.getKey(), "").isEmpty();`. For the title of the question there is an API `containsKey` such as `a.getMap().containsKey(b.getKey())`

Comment: For clarification, in the real code the map came from the database, so I do need to check using StringUtils::isBlank

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do this? Really the whole point of maps is to allow fast access to values via their keys so it'd be unusual to then iterate through map entries just to do the same thing. If you can explain what you are trying to achieve there could be better advice than converting to a stream.

Comment: If you want a concise solution, omit the unnecessary local variables, `(a, b) -> !StringUtils.isBlank(a.getMap().get(b.getKey()))`. Turning an `O(1)` (or `O(log n)` in case of TreeMap) operation into an `O(n)` operation makes no sense at all.